# blender 2.8 FBX importing problem?

Tags: import

I am trying to load some scenes to blender from 3ds max

when I try import fbx, these info showed up

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\A Program\blender-2.81-windows64\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx__init__.py", line 216, in execute
    if import_fbx.load(self, context, filepath=path, **keywords) == {'FINISHED'}:
  File "C:\A Program\blender-2.81-windows64\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2810, in load
    _(); del _
  File "C:\A Program\blender-2.81-windows64\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2804, in _
    root_helper.build_hierarchy(fbx_tmpl, settings, scene, view_layer)
  File "C:\A Program\blender-2.81-windows64\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2242, in build_hierarchy
    child.build_hierarchy(fbx_tmpl, settings, scene, view_layer)
  File "C:\A Program\blender-2.81-windows64\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2233, in build_hierarchy
    child.build_hierarchy(fbx_tmpl, settings, scene, view_layer)
  File "C:\A Program\blender-2.81-windows64\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2229, in build_hierarchy
    obj = self.build_node_obj(fbx_tmpl, settings)
  File "C:\A Program\blender-2.81-windows64\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2041, in build_node_obj
    blen_read_custom_properties(self.fbx_elem, obj, settings)
  File "C:\A Program\blender-2.81-windows64\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 331, in blen_read_custom_properties
    prop_name, prop_value = item.split('=', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

location: :-1

what's the problem , how can I fix it ?